# Как уcтранить "Connection Closed Gracefully"?

Tags: delphi, indy

Есть код отправки почты:

```
procedure SendMail(aFrom, aPassword, aTo: string; aData: string; aUserMail: string);
var
  zSMTP: TIdSMTP;
  zEmail: TIdMessage;
  zSSLHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  zAttachment: TIdAttachmentFile;
begin
  zSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
  try
    zEmail := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
    try
      zSSLHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
      try
        zSSLHandler.MaxLineAction := maException;
        zSSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
        zSSLHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
        zSSLHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
        zSSLHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

        zSMTP.IOHandler := zSSLHandler;
        zSMTP.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
        zSMTP.Port := 587;
        zSMTP.Username := aFrom;
        zSMTP.Password := aPassword;
        zSMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;

        zEmail.From.Address := 'program';
        zEmail.Recipients.EmailAddresses := aTo;
        zEmail.Subject := 'Регистрация';
        zEmail.Body.Text := '';
        zEmail.CharSet := 'koi8-r';
        try
          zSMTP.Connect;
          zSMTP.Send(zEmail);
          zSMTP.Disconnect;
          ShowMessage('Письмо успешно отправлено. Ожидайте ответа на почту ' + aUserMail);
        except on e: Exception do
          ShowMessage('Не удалось отправить письмо! ' + e.Message);
        end;
      finally
        FreeAndNil(zSSLHandler);
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(zEmail);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(zSMTP);
  end;
end;
```

При отправке с некоторых компьютеров возвращается ошибка

> Connection Closed Gracefully

на некоторых нормально. При этом письмо не отправляется. Антивирус и брандмауэр отключал. Не помогает.

У меня Windows 7, Delphi XE 3, Indy 10.5.9.0

Comment: Емнип, Indy должны использовать OpenSSL lib? Поставляете ли с программой эти dll? Сталкивался с подобным на https, решал явным "покладанием" этих dll-ок в папку с экзешником.

Comment: Лежат. Дело в том что с моего рабочего компьютера отправляется и с другого нет. код один и тот же с теми же самыми dll ками

Comment: А могут ли порты 587, 495 быть заблокированы провайдером или каким либо софтом на компе ?

Comment: Провайдером - на 99,9% - нет. А про "какой-то софт" вы же сами написали, что брандмауэр отключен.

Comment: Как тогда обходить эту ситуацию если надо отправить почту, но у пользователя стоит антивирус или брандмауэр заблокировал. Я пишу программу которая у запускается у пользователя и по его согласию отправляет почту с данными. Не будет же он ковыряться в настройках. Уже пробовал библиотеку Synapse, но там на моем компе работает а у пользователя валится на функции Login.   Если есть кусочек кода -поделитесь.

Comment: Просить пользователя. От того, какой набор компонентов вы задействуете - ничего не зависит. Проверять на старте возможность коннекта и предупреждать его. Теоретически, есть возможность вмешаться в штатный брандмауэр и добавить себя в исключения (нужно повышение прав). И то - я бы отправил такое приложение фтопку. Но что вы будете делать с Outpost, Kaspersky, Kerio и 100500 других сторонних? Поэтому правильный путь - просить пользователя.